# Changing Hidden input with Href Javascript call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, href, hidden

I am writing a page that grabs images from a url the user inputs, and using ajax, am updating a div with the img src to be displayed by fancybox in a modal window. The images that are displayed have titles displayed below, as links. This is done with fancybox (If you set the title as set the `title="something"` will display "something" below the image. If you set the title as `title="<a href='something.html'>Something</a>`)

My problem is this. I need to allow the user to choose an image by clicking the link, and in turn have it do 2 things: update the hidden field with the src url of the img, and submit the form.

Here is the code I have for the ajax request:

```
    function getCustomerInfo() {
        var phone = document.getElementById("urls").value;
        var url = "grabimages.php?urls=" + escape(phone);
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
        request.send(null);
        $("#dvloader").show();
        $("#selectimages").hide();
        //$("#noimages").hide();

        function updatePage() {
        if (request.readyState == 4)
            if (request.status == 200){
                if(request.responseText == ''){
                    $("#dvloader").hide();
                    $("#noimages").show();
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("update-div").innerHTML = request.responseText;
                    $("#dvloader").hide();
                    $("#selectimages").show();
                    $(".fancybox")
                        .attr('rel', 'gallery')
                        .fancybox({
                            padding : 15
                        });
                    $('input[id=theimage]').click(function(){

                        $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click');
                    }); 


                    function recURL(recipeurl) {

                        $('#recipeurl').val('recipeurl');
                        document.recipeform.submit();


                    }

                }
            }else{
                alert('nothing');
            }

        }
```

And here is the code I tried for the href javascript call (this is the server side code, so PHP:

```
    echo "<a class=\"fancybox\" id=\"recipelinks\" title=\"<a href='#' onclick='javascript:recURL(" . $imagepath . ");'>Choose this Image</a>\" href=\"" . $imagepath . "\"><img src=\"" . $imagepath . "\" alt=\"\"/></a>";
```

This doesn't do anything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$('.fancybody').live('click', function() { });`, `live` allows you to listen for events on elements which are added to the `DOM` dynamically.

Comment: So, if I use `$('.fancybox').live('click', function() { });` I need to be able to use the dynamic url in the function. How can this be done? So, i need something like this: `$('.fancybox').live('click', function(recURL) { $('#recipeurl').val('recipeurl');document.recipeform.submit();
});` I assume that this will call the code every time a link with the class of fancybox is clicked, I just don't know how to keep track of which link is being clicked specifically.

Comment: I got it. I used your code, but made some modifications to adapt to my own 

        `$('.recTitle').live('click', function(){ 
      
       var rURL = $(this).attr('rel');
       document.getElementById("recURL").value = rURL;
       $.fancybox.close( true );
      });`

Comment: @StevenJohnson sorry I missed your first reply.. also notice I spelt fancybox wrong, oops. Glad you got it solved!